# Identifying what group policy applies which printer

Tags: printer, group-policy

So at work there are thousands of printers and hundreds of printer group policy groups.

How can I identify which group will deploy which printer?

Please disregard naming conventions etc.

I would like to know which ways it is possible, I have looked online and most advice is for deploying printers with a group policy which is not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to a domain such as yours, but below is what I found.
I assume that you're using Windows inside a domain, so the best tool
to use would be PowerShell.

The article
[Getting a list of printers published in an Active Directory domain](https://blog.wisefaq.com/2015/10/22/getting-a-list-of-printers-published-in-an-active-directory-domain/)
has this PowerShell command-line to get a list of print servers
and printers in the domain:

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectCategory=printQueue)" -Properties cn, drivername, location, printername, portname, servername | select portname, cn, drivername, location, printername, servername | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File C:\wisefaq\printerlist.txt
```

Another useful article is
[Get printer names, IP addresses and drivers from a computer using WMI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/346533/get-printer-names-ip-addresses-and-drivers-from-a.html)
which contains a PowerShell script that requires as input the list
of printer servers in your domain:

```
$ReportFileName = "C:\printerreport.csv" 
$PrintServersList="C:\PrintServersList.txt"         
$servers =  Get-Content -Path $PrintServersList 
$allprinters = @()  
foreach( $server in $servers ){ 
  Write-Host "checking $server ..." 
  $printers = $null 
  $printers = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Printer -computername $server | 
  select Name,Shared,ShareName,Local, DriverName, PortName,
  @{n="PrinterIp";e={(((gwmi win32_tcpipprinterport -ComputerName $server -filter "name='$($_.PortName)'") | select HostAddress).HostAddress)}},
  @{n='PrintServer';e={$_.SystemName}}, Location,Comment,SpoolEnabled,Published,
  @{n='Trustee Name';e={(($_.GetSecurityDescriptor()).Descriptor.DACL.Trustee.Name | Select-Object -Unique) -join ','}}
  @{n='Trustee SID';e={($_.GetSecurityDescriptor()).Descriptor.DACL.Trustee.SIDString -join ','}}
  $allprinters += $printers  
}     
Write-Host "exporting to printers.csv" 
$allprinters | Export-CSV -Path $ReportFileName -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8
Write-Host "Done!"
```

For identifying GPO and printers, see the article
[Get all GPO deployed Printers with PowerShell](https://365lab.net/2014/01/07/get-all-gpo-deployed-printers-with-powershell/).
The script itself is too long, but I list it here anyway.
You may find instructions on its use in the article.

**Get-GPOPrinters.ps1**

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS     
The script finds all shared printers deployed with GPO (both deployed printers GPP.) in your domain. 
.NOTES     
           File Name: Get-GPOPrinters.ps1     
           Author   : Johan Dahlbom, johan[at]dahlbom.eu     
           The script are provided “AS IS” with no guarantees, no warranties, and it confer no rights. 
           Blog     : 365lab.net
#>
#Import the required module GroupPolicy
try
{
Import-Module GroupPolicy -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
throw "Module GroupPolicy not Installed"
}
$GPO = Get-GPO -All

foreach ($Policy in $GPO){

        $GPOID = $Policy.Id
        $GPODom = $Policy.DomainName
        $GPODisp = $Policy.DisplayName
        $PrefPath = "\\$($GPODom)\SYSVOL\$($GPODom)\Policies\{$($GPOID)}\User\Preferences"

            #Get GP Preferences Printers
            $XMLPath = "$PrefPath\Printers\Printers.xml"
            if (Test-Path "$XMLPath")
            {
                 [xml]$PrintXML = Get-Content "$XMLPath"

                        foreach ( $Printer in $PrintXML.Printers.SharedPrinter )

                            {New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                GPOName = $GPODisp
                                PrinterPath = $printer.Properties.Path
                                PrinterAction = $printer.Properties.action.Replace("U","Update").Replace("C","Create").Replace("D","Delete").Replace("R","Replace")
                                PrinterDefault = $printer.Properties.default.Replace("0","False").Replace("1","True")
                                FilterGroup = $printer.Filters.FilterGroup.Name
                                GPOType = "Group Policy Preferences"
                            }
                        }
           }
           #Get Deployed Printers
           [xml]$xml = Get-GPOReport -Id $GPOID -ReportType xml
           $User = $xml.DocumentElement.User.ExtensionData.extension.printerconnection
           $Computer = $xml.DocumentElement.computer.ExtensionData.extension.printerconnection

                foreach ($U in $User){
                    if ($U){

                            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                GPOName = $GPODisp
                                PrinterPath = $u.Path
                                GPOType = "GPO Deployed Printer - User"
                            }
                    }

                }

                foreach ($C in $Computer){
                    if ($c){

                            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                GPOName = $GPODisp
                                PrinterPath = $c.Path
                                GPOType = "GPO Deployed Printer - Computer"
                            }
                    }

                }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, unless it is properly documented somewhere, you'll need powershell to query this. +1

Comment: @harrymc I can connect to the print server and access the printers there, I can see all of the group policies but how can I identify which printer corresponds to which group? 

If I run a powershell script to return printers and server details, it will return thousands of results

Comment: See the addition to my answer with the Get-GPOPrinters.ps1 script.